# ms-access 2003 scheduled backup

Tags: ms-access-2003

I have been researching the possibility of scheduling an automatic back up of a database, but every link on the subject just talks about the manual back up process.  Can anyone either show how to accomplish setting up a scheduled back up or a link to a good wab based training on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Access is a file based system, so you can use script or a batch file to run in Task Sceduler at any time that you are sure the database will be closed. For example: http://www.overclock.net/t/114345/how-to-automatically-backup-files

Answer (score 1):

We were running an MS Access system for several years and this is how we implemented a backup system.

1. Our system was split into multiple databases - import, backend and front-end
2. We had a dedicated desktop PC to run the process. This machine ran the import process and always had the import database open.
3. There was a form that would be open in the import database with a timer on it.
4. The timer had code that would run scheduled processes including - import process and backups and even compacting of the database.

There are other ways to perform this type of task, but this was the system that we had.

There are a few drawbacks, including:

1. If the desktop machine reboots, then the database is closed and nothing will run.